# why does it give me mximum call stack size exceeded?

Tags: reactjs, promise, callstack

i have this working version of this code that loops over the array of LocalCart and does stuff with the product inside of it with the name of (element)

```
  const AddToPending = async () => {
setIsLoading(true);
if (LocalCart.length === 0) {
  CreateToast("Please add some items to the cart first", "error");
  return;
}
const PendingOrders = activeUser.pending;
const FetchedUser = await GETDOC("users", activeUser.id);
for (const element of LocalCart) {
  const now = new Date();

  date.format(now, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
  const fetchedStatistics = await GETDOC("statistics", 0);
  const fetchedProduct = await GETDOC("products", element.id);
  if (fetchedProduct.stock > 0) {
    PendingOrders.push(element);
    const updatedUser = {
      ...FetchedUser,
      cart: [],
      pending: PendingOrders,
    };
    const updatedStatistics = {
      ...fetchedStatistics,
      PendingOrders: [
        ...fetchedStatistics.PendingOrders,
        {
          product: element,
          user: activeUser,
          ID: generateId(),
          CreatedAt: date.format(now, pattern),
        },
      ],
      CartNum: fetchedStatistics.CartNum - 1,
    };
    await SETDOC("statistics", 0, updatedStatistics);
    setActiveUser(updatedUser);
    setLocalCart(updatedUser.cart);
    props.setUpdateCart((prev) => prev - 1);
    CreateToast(
      `${element.title} Added to pending orders, we will let you know when its confirmed!`,
      "success"
    );
  } else {
    CreateToast(
      `${element.title} wasn't added, it's out of stock`,
      "error"
    );
  }
}
setIsLoading(false); };
```

and its working fine but the issue comes when i do this

```
const AddToPending = async () => {
setIsLoading(true);
if (LocalCart.length === 0) {
  CreateToast("Please add some items to the cart first", "error");
  return;
}
const PendingOrders = activeUser.pending;
const FetchedUser = await GETDOC("users", activeUser.id);
for (const element of LocalCart) {
  const now = new Date();
  date.format(now, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
  let Order = {
    product: element,
    user: activeUser,
    ID: generateId(),
    CreatedAt: date.format(now, pattern),
  };
  const fetchedStatistics = await GETDOC("statistics", 0);
  const fetchedProduct = await GETDOC("products", element.id);
  if (fetchedProduct.stock > 0) {
    PendingOrders.push(Order);
    const updatedUser = {
      ...FetchedUser,
      cart: [],
      pending: PendingOrders,
    };
    const updatedStatistics = {
      ...fetchedStatistics,
      PendingOrders: [...fetchedStatistics.PendingOrders, Order],
      CartNum: fetchedStatistics.CartNum - 1,
    };
    await SETDOC("statistics", 0, updatedStatistics);
    setActiveUser(updatedUser);
    setLocalCart(updatedUser.cart);
    props.setUpdateCart((prev) => prev - 1);
    CreateToast(
      `${element.title} Added to pending orders, we will let you know when its confirmed!`,
      "success"
    );
  } else {
    CreateToast(
      `${element.title} wasn't added, it's out of stock`,
      "error"
    );
  }
}
setIsLoading(false);};
```

the change that happened is that i made "Order" a variable and used it in 2 places

then it throws this error

> caught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

additional codes

```
  const pattern = date.compile("h:mm ddd, MMM DD YYYY");
  function generateId() {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000);
    const id = randomNumber.toString().padStart(8, "0");
    return id;}
```

```
export const SETDOC = async (
  collection = String,
  id = Number,
  newValue = Object,
  New = ""
) => {
  if (New) {
    await setDoc(doc(db, collection, id.toString()), newValue);
  }
  const res = await GETDOC(collection, id);
  if (res === "Error") {
    throw new Error("No data found");
  } else {
    await setDoc(doc(db, collection, id.toString()), newValue);
  }
};
```

```
export const GETDOC = async (collection = String, id = Number) => {
  try {
    const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, collection, id.toString()));
    if (docSnap.exists()) {
      return docSnap.data();
    } else {
      return "Error";
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
```

i think the issue might be in repeated calling of function

```
generateId()
```

because its inside a loop ,but i even tried to call it outside the loop and increment it by one each time and yet still showed error